# Handling Promise and Observable on same variable in Node.js & Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

In my project, I have an image.

On initialization; I load it from a `Promise<string>`; where string is a **URL to the image**

Then I use a node package to change and crop the image. It asks for an image, crops it to the requested size and returns an `Observable<anObject>` where the `anObject.base64` is a base64 representation of the cropped image. It's contained in a dialog.

I tried many many things but could not change the image of the `<img>` tag automatically.

Here is my last setup:

```
image: Observable<string>;
...

ngOnInit() {

    ...

    prd.images.big.then(img => {
        this.image = of(img);
    });
    // prd.images.big is a Promise<string>

    ...
}


showImageDialog() {
    this.image = this.imageDialog.openDialog().pipe(
        map(data => {
            return data.base64;
        })
    );
}
```

And my template:
    ....

```
<a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="showImageDialog();">
    <img [src]="(image | async) || 'an url to default image'"/>
</a>

....
```

Weird thing is, image not change automatically, but when I click on the image again, it changes.

I hope any of you can help to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid re-assigning the observable once you create it.  Try something like this:

```
image: Subject<string>;
...

ngOnInit() {

    this.image = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

    prd.images.big.then(img => this.image.next(img));
}

showImageDialog() {
    this.imageDialog.openDialog().subscribe(data => {
       const dataUrl = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${data.base64}`;
       this.image.next(dataUrl);
    });
}
```

FYI a Subject is just a variable that acts as both observer and observable-you can subscribe or pipe operations from it like any observable and you can also manually put values into the subject that will then be observed by all of the subscribers. In the code above I used a special kind of subject that will replay the most recent value to any late subscribers just in case you put a value in before the view has time to subscribe.

Comment: OMG! Thank you! Using `Subject` solved my problem. But, I really do not know what is subject; I never used and have never seen a usage of it before.

Comment: Oops. Now I have another problem. After I first image selection and cropping done; when I try to select another image via `<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />` browser freezes for a while, ~10 secs. Before using `Subject` it wasn't happening.

Comment: What are you doing in your filechangeeventhandler?  You should just be just using FileReader readAsDataUrl and taking the resulting string and calling `this.image.next(dataurl)`

Comment: My `ngx-image-cropper` handling that via $event.

Comment: OK. Found the problem. I didn't add a file mime checker on file input at first. And accidentally selected a dmg file with size of gigs. Then, of course, Safari froze. I force closed it, and restarted angular server. Even then this file upload event remained alive, don't know how, and for a short time freeze the browsers. I restarted the computer. Now everything is ok. Should be a macOS or Angular CLI bug I suppose. Thank you for everything!

Comment: Probably time for a new question to help track that down

Answer (score 1):

You are currently assigning a subscription to this.image. Instead, set this.image to be the data.base64 returned inside your map function. If you want to use base64-encoded image bytes for an image tag, you need to use a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

If your image type is jpeg:
`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{image}}"/>`

Comment: So, you suggest me to change `image` variable to `string` from `Observable`? Am I right?

Comment: BTW, I made a mistake while copying the code from IDE to here. Look at my template code again.

Comment: Yes, I suggest that. Also I suggest to use my provided img tag for template instead of what you have. Replace the image/jpeg if needed according to the image format you have

Comment: I have an error: `Failed to load resource: unsupported URL
unsafe:data:image/jpeg;base64,http://url.to.image`... Gosh! I hate web things!

Comment: The src shouldn't have an actual URL in it, but the {{image}} should hold the image bytes base64-encoded returned by your library

Comment: `showImageDialog()` returns base64, yes. But `prd.images.big` is a `Promise<string>` where string is a **URL to the image**... I wish I had a `UIImage` like class... Sorry, I edited my question. Missed to mention the URL.